# How to create a Multi-step form with different flows depending on the user's choice

Tags: jquery

I am creating a multi-step form with different tabs to display (for example, eight tabs). On the third tab, I am asking the user to choose one option from option 1, option 2, and option 3; when the user selects one option, the flow will be changed.
Example:

- If the user chooses option 1, I need to display only tabs that have class (option1)
- If the user chooses option 2, I need to display only tabs that have class (option2)
- If the user chooses option 3, I need to display only tabs that have class (option3)

Below Is the code.

```js
    var currentTab = 0;
    var formValues = {}; // Object to store form values

    showTab(currentTab);

    function showTab(n) {
        var x = $(".tab");
        x.addClass("hidden");
        x.eq(n).removeClass("hidden");

        // Restore form values from object
        var inputs = x.eq(n).find("input, select, textarea");
        inputs.each(function () {
            var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            if (formValues.hasOwnProperty(inputName)) {
                $(this).val(formValues[inputName]);
            }
        });

        if (n == 0) {
            $("#prevBtn").addClass("invisible");
        } else {
            $("#prevBtn").removeClass("invisible");
        }

        if (n == x.length - 1) {
            $("#nextBtn").html("ارسال");
        } else {
            // $("#nextBtn").html("Next");
        }
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
        var x = $(".tab");
        var isValid = validateForm();

        if (n == 1 && !isValid) return false;

        x.eq(currentTab).addClass("hidden");

        // Save form values to object
        var inputs = x.eq(currentTab).find("input, select, textarea");
        inputs.each(function () {
            var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            var inputValue = $(this).val();
            formValues[inputName] = inputValue;
        });

        currentTab += n;

        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            $("#admissionForm").submit();
            return false;
        }

        showTab(currentTab);
    }

function validateForm() {
  var x = $(".tab");
  var y = x.eq(currentTab).find("input, select, textarea");
  var valid = true;
  var errorInput = null;
  var validationMessage = $('.validation-message');

  y.each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
      $(this).addClass("border-red-500");
      valid = false;
      errorInput = this;
      var labelFor = $(this).attr("id");
      if (labelFor) {
        var label = $('label[for="' + labelFor + '"]');
        label.addClass("border-red-500");
      }
      validationMessage.text('يرجى التحقق من جميع الحقول').addClass('text-red-500').removeClass('text-green-500');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("border-red-500");
      var labelFor = $(this).attr("id");
      if (labelFor) {
        var label = $('label[for="' + labelFor + '"]');
        label.removeClass("border-red-500");
      }
    }
  });
  
  // Check if the current tab contains the #multiple-select id, and skip validation if it does
  if (x.eq(currentTab).find('#multiple-select').length) {
    return true;
  }

  if (valid) {
    validationMessage.text('شكرا تم تعبئة الحقل بشكل صحيح.').addClass('text-green-500').removeClass('text-red-500');
  }

  return valid;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <div class="tab">
    Tab one content here
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab one -->

  <div class="tab">
    Tab one content here
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab two -->

  <div class="tab">
    Tab Three content here
    <br />
    <br />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select an Option</legend>

        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="option1" name="select-option" value="option1"
                checked>
          <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="option2" name="select-option" value="option2">
          <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="option3" name="select-option" value="option3">
          <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
        <br />
    <br />

    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab three -->


  <div class="tab option1">
    Tab Four Only shown if the user choosed option 1 in tab3
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab Four -->

  <div class="tab option2">
    Only shown if the user choosed option 2 in tab3 
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab Five -->


  <div class="tab option3">
    Only shown if the user chooses option 3 in tab3 
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab six -->


  <div class="tab option1 option 3">
     Only shown if the user choosed option 1 or option 2 in tab3 
        <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
  <div>
  <!-- end tab Five -->
    
    tab

</form>
```

Comment: You need to add a working snippet

Comment: Your `.tab` elements seem to be nested. This can't be intended.

Comment: I think it will be hard to manage which tabs are part of the current workflow by using classes. I would try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/fajgwv02/